# CSS Hover & onmouseover/out causing 15-20% CPU Usage in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, performance, internet-explorer

is there any reason why Internet Explorer (IE7 in my case) gets sluggish and eats up lots of CPU time when using the CSS :hover command or using onmouseover/onmouseout?

I'm really not doing anything complex, nor is my page particularly large.

When I move my mouse anywhere else on the page (where nothing is changing) iexplore.exe stays at 0%, but once I start moving across any element that has onmouseover/onmouseout or a CSS hover class attached to it, things get really slow and sluggish and CPU usage gets high.

**The page works perfectly fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari** with not speed issues/sluggishness whatsoever.

Hints/Ideas?

**Edit:** The onmouseover/onmouseout is on **<tr>** tags (highlighting a row in a grid); the CSS:hover is used on **<a>** tags swapping a background-image url.

Comment: You aren't doing anything complicated, but you are doing something.  So, can you show what you are doing?  If you do it with CSS will it have the same effect?

Comment: Yes, both CSS and OnMouseOver/OnMouseOut have the same result. The only thing I can think of - I have lots of CSS background images in my page and for different elements (maybe about 50 altogether). But that's not causing a problem in any of the other browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a *non-flicker* CSS rollover (which doesn't trigger continual 'hover' signals with every tiny mouse movement). Swapping images on hover generally doesn't work too well, especially in IE.

The best way to do this without a Javascript library is to have the desired 'hover' image as a *background* to the element *beneath* the one you're hovering over, and the *non-hover* image as a background to the element *in front*.

Then for the CSS `:hover` state of the element *in front*, set `background-image: none; background-color: transparent;` so that the desired 'hover' image in the underlying element is revealed.

Check the source code for this [example non-flicker CSS rollover](http://ecoconsulting.co.uk/examples/css-rollover/).

Depending on your markup, you may need to adjust the `z-index` value to get the top element 'in front' of the underlying one.

Answer (score 0):

> not doing anything complex

Well, what **are** you doing? I've seen this just from changing the background tr color. IE doesn't seem to be good at this.

Comment: That's (on *tr*) where I have the onmouseover/onmousout. It's a grid and I need to highlight the row somehow. The CSS:hover is on anchor tags, switching a background-image url around when hovered.

Comment: Don't change the background image on the tr, that's the worst performance-wise. Just change the color, it will improve things a lot.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The tr change is in fact only a color change. The anchor tags are the ones with the image.